# Alternative to MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

is there an alternative to MFMailComposeViewController that has more-or-less the same functionality, but that will let me handle the sending of the email myself, outside of Apples email-sending system?

What I want to do is to provide a nice email dialog, and then send it through a CRM system instead of directly from the iPad.

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 3):

YES, You can use the MailCore Framework. You can handle the sending of email by yourself. Before sending the mail you have to set its fields such as To,CC,BCC,Subject,body etc and then send by the following code..

```
CTCoreMessage *msg = [[CTCoreMessage alloc] init];
[CTSMTPConnection sendMessage:msg server:[server stringValue] username:[username stringValue]
                         password:[password stringValue] port:[port intValue] useTLS:tls useAuth:auth];
 [msg release];
```

It works for me fine. Hope it will help you..

Comment: I have not seen MailCore have a UI? Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Yes you are right the MailCore has no UI. You have to use the Three20 Framework for the UI with the MailCore. The MFMailComposeViewController just allow users to send an email via their existing Mail.app accounts...

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create your own email view and handler. You can use something like JSTokenField : https://github.com/jasarien/JSTokenField to get the functionality on the mail "To:" field.